# Selecting other Tables of database to show on a DataGridView

Tags: c#, mysql, database, winforms, datagridview

I want to display many tables of data in my datagridview.

I use combobox to select other tables but it can't read and can't show table, so I set my combobox to its 1st table but every time I refresh the table it always getting back to the table I set

```
 private void UpdateDataGrid()
    {
        using (IDbConnection dbconnection = new SQLiteConnection(conn))
        {
            dbconnection.Open();

           //the other tables are Electrical and Tools
            cbTable.Text = "Plumbing";
            SQLiteDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM  " + cbTable.Text + "", conn);
            ds = new System.Data.DataSet();

            dataAdapter.Fill(ds, "Item_InFo");
            dgvItems.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        }
    }
```

Comment: From where are you calling UpdateDataGrid? Have you used IsPostBack?

Comment: R u using dataset

Comment: Where do you set the cbTable.Text? Because it's static in the code you show.

Comment: if u r ssing the data set. u can store them in dictonary , while selecting each value form the combobox check that values id is there in dictonary, if yes, load that datatable

Comment: how do you setup your initial table? do you first set cbTable.Text and then call the UpdateDataGrid method? or is it done with binding?

Comment: Your code sets `cbTable.Text` to "Plumbing". Where do you get the selected item from the combobox?

Comment: im calling the UpdateDataGrid to the load function of my form